# how to use Bootstrap-4 in project?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm new to bootstrap4 so please explain how to use it in the project.

In Bootstrap 4 there are folders like dist, js etc,

1. In dist folder again js folder...so which js file has to use in the project.
2. In the main js folder, there are affix.js, button.js, collapse.js etc files are there.

I) what are the use of above js files where we use those plugins in bootstrap3
without any js files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What tutorials have you followed?

Comment: Why do not you use bootstrap-3.3.7-dist?
Easily add three original folders to your project. Includes js and css and fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using Bootstrap 4.0.0, the latest version, there is a "crash course" on Coursetro:

https://coursetro.com/posts/code/130/Learn-Bootstrap-4-Final-in-2018-with-our-Free-Crash-Course

The course starts with installing Bootstrap 4.0.0 and ends with a simple project. It has a coursevideo too.
For editing the files you need during the course, you can use the free "Visual Studio Code" as was advised in an earlier course on Coursetro.
https://code.visualstudio.com/

I only use Bootstrap for about 3 months, so I am new too.
Follow the above mentioned course to get the hang of it.

The folder you mention:

> node_modules>bootstrap>js>dist

is used by Bootstrap itself as far as i know. And the file affix.js is not present in Bootstrap 4.0.0 anymore only in an older version. If you depend on those files you might get into trouble with newer Bootstrap versions.

As soon as for instance you use this in your index.html:
`<div class="nav-item dropdown">`
bootstrap "knows" it should use "dropdown.js"
There is no need for you to know anything about that file.

The only folder that is important for your project is:

> node_modules>bootstrap>dist

Comment: note : Plugins can be included individually (using Bootstrap’s individual js/dist/*.js), or all at once using bootstrap.js or the minified bootstrap.min.js (don’t include both).
If you use a bundler (Webpack, Rollup…), you can use /js/dist/*.js files which are UMD ready.https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

> In dist folder again js folder...so which js file has to use in the project.

You will see 2 folders in dist folder-> js and css

Use the js file bootstrap.min.js

For css use the file bootstrap.min.css

> I) what are the use of above js files where we use those plugins in bootstrap3 without any js files.

These are files for individual components. During build its concatenated and minified to bootstrap.min.js

If you don't use the components you can comment these files during build and generate your custom bootstrap file.